# Unable to create a Controller in Symfony 5 : Expected to find class

Tags: php, symfony

I specify that I am not a beginner with Symfony. It's not about creating a Controller, but an error I get when I try to create a Controller. I also specify that it is about an already existing website which comprise approximately 10 controllers.

To create a controller, I tried several methods:

- Create the controller from zero by hand
- Copy-paste an existing controller
- With the command line via the method: `symfony console make:controller NomController`

Either way, I got the following error:

> Expected to find class "App\Controller\NomController" in file "C:\wamp64\www\dev\nom-site\src\Controller\NomController.php" while importing services from resource "../src/", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in C:\wamp64\www\dev\nom-site\src../config/services.yaml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\dev\nom-site\src\Kernel.php").

Obviously, the `NomController` class exists in the `NomController.php` file and:

- there is no syntax error because I have already tried with an empty and almost empty class.
- I cleared the caches in var > cache

Here is the `services.yaml` file:

```yaml
services:

    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'
```

I tested to add a new

- service in src\Service\TestService.php.
- type in src\Form\Type\TestType.php

I have exactly the same error. In fact, it is not a problem specific to controllers. It can be a modification so that symfony keeps in cache all the PHP classes (gain in performance).

Comment: what is the path to your NomController?

Comment: Also can you post your NomController file (no need for the class content)

Comment: @craigh, the path of NameController is: src\Controller\PageController.php

Comment: @DylanKAS, Even if the class is empty, there is still the same error.

Comment: I did not meant to empty it, just post it to be sure your namespace is App\Controller\NomController and you class is NomController

Comment: @Jaquarh symfony controllers are stored in src/Controller (App\Controller) by default

Comment: post your config/services.yaml file

Comment: These are often a case problem.  Make sure the file name is exactly NomController.php.  And then double check the class name is exactly NomController.  Any case difference will trigger the error.  Your comment about NameController being in PageController.php is very strange.

Comment: @DylanKAS, namespace is App\Controller\NomController and the file is located in src/Controller/NameController.php (As I mentioned in my first post, I'm not a beginner with symfony) :

`<?php
// src/Controller/NomController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class NomController extends AbstractController
{

}
`

Comment: @craigh, I edited the original post to add services.yaml

Comment: @Cerad, I checked, it's not a cas or syntax issue.

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload` ? also does your composer.json has the autoload psr-4 config with `/src` ?

Comment: You got me stumped.  You are using windows so that is always a bit of a red flag.  Maybe a PHP version mismatch between server and command line? Seems unlikely.  At this point I might make a new 5.4 app and run make:controller just to see if anything is working.  Might even resort to turning the computer off and then back on.

Comment: @DylanKAS, Well done, that’s it! Thank you so much. Every time I add a new class, I have to do: composer dump-autoload... It's annoying, but it's a site that only needs tweaking!

Comment: @DylanKAS, it's good, I did: upvote and validated. Thanks again. I had left a lot of time and energy for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons that could cause this issue.

**1. Check your class name and namespace (case sensitive)**

In your case, your class name must be `NomController`, namespace `App\Controller\NomController` and located in `src/Controller/NomController`

**2. Check for syntax errors**

Weirdly enough, this error can pop up for other reasons such as a missing colon ;

**3. Check your composer.json for your autoload config**

With symfony default configuration, it should look like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

You can then run `composer dump-autoload` to generate manually your `vendor/autoload.php` file (used by your index.php).